# Call CURD operation of a class from another class

Tags: python, django, class

I have a class with create, update, and delete functions of Django CRUD
Can I use the create, and update functions of first in another class create function

from example :

```
class A(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

     def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     some code 
     
     def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
     some code
```

Now as you can see the first class A have create and update function
Now I have another class B which also a have create function
now how can use call the create function of first class A

```
class B(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

     def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     some code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly call the other class from the class you want
just use .create function and pass the required param

Answer (score 0):

First of, I agree with Yussef's answer. It should be working.

An alterntive would be inheritance:

```py
class B(A):  # let B inherit from A
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("here your logic")
        super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)  # call the function of parent class
        print("some more logic")
```

Sure, inheritance brings along more advantages, but those might also be disadvantage if it does not suit your needs. Because by inheriting from `A`, your class `B` now also has the same `update` function as `A`. Normal inheritance behaviour